# What being diffeomorphic means (except that there is a diffeomorphism)?

Tags: real-analysis, diffeomorphism

I was wondering what exactly "$A$ and $B$ are diffeomorphic" means (instead of "having a diffeomorphism $f:A\to B$). I know the definition of a diffeomorphism. For example, the set $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic means that as topological spaces they are the same. I.e. topological property of $A$ and of $B$ are identical.

What would it be for diffeomorphism ? What for example it would mean that : if $f:\Omega \to \mathbb R^m$ is a $\mathcal C^1$ function where $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ is open : there are two diffeomorphism $u: U\to P$ and $v: V\to Q$ (where $U\subset \Omega $, $P\subset \mathbb R^n$, $V,Q\subset \mathbb R^m $ open) s.t. $$v\circ f\circ u^{-1}(x_1,...,x_n)=(x_1,...,x_r,0,...,0).$$

I know that is (more or less) the constant rank theorem, but it's not the problem. Why the fact that $u$ and $v$ are diffeomorphism is important ? How can I interpret 
$$v\circ f\circ u^{-1}(x_1,...,x_n)=(x_1,...,x_r,0,...,0) \ \ ?$$
Would it be that $f$ is more or less the application $(x_1,...,x_n)\longmapsto (x_1,...,x_r,0,...,0)$ ? And if $u$ and $v$ where just bijection, why it would be bad ?

Comment: Continuity doesn't "see" kinks, bends, and sharp edges (read transversality). Only rips. Differentiability however can "see" kinks and bends and sharp edges. If they're present in one, they're present in something that is diffeomorphic to it.